# const double & in template class partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, partial-specialization

Suppose the following definitions:

```
#define AA(x) A<decltype(x), x>

template<typename T, T x>
struct A;

template<int a>
struct A<int, a>{};

template<bool b>
struct A<bool, b>{};

template<const double &d>
struct A<const double &, d>{};

extern constexpr double myDouble = 0.2;
```

After these definitions, the following works:

```
AA(false) myA2;
```

However, the compiler complains when it sees this:

```
AA(myDouble) myA3;
```

It says:

> ‘const double’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
>
> #define AA(x) A

On the other hand, the compiler is perfectly happy with this:

```
A<const double &, myDouble> myA1;
```

What is the reason for this compiler error? (using `g++` version 4.8.2)

Comment: Clearly, `decltype<myDouble>` is `const double` and not `const double&`

Comment: Ah! Got caught on this twice today!